# IBM ACE: Unknown SFTP Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.jcraft.Compression

Tags: ibm-app-connect

I am trying to send file to sftp from IBM ace rest api application getting below exception:

**Unknown SFTP Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.jcraft.Compression**

Comment: are you trying to achieve with any File Nodes?

Comment: Are you using MQ FTE, or File nodes? The former does indeed appear to not have that class, but the latter does contain the class so it *should* work.  Some more information about the usage would be handy to figure out the path it's taking to get to the error.